# test/production shcema mongodb synchronization

Tags: mongodb, synchronization, schema

I am a new in mongodb development coming from SQL environemnt.
I have a question about test/prod sync:
is there a way/tool to publish the changes (like validations and indexes) that are created in a collection in the test environment to production?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the build in option [changeStreams](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/)

Comment: I need it for schema changes only not data change

Comment: Aaah indeed changeStreams concern only data changes , the schema ( indexes , validations ) you will need to do manually , there is some nice tools out there , compass has schema export : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/master/schema/export/

Comment: in mongodb 6.0 changeStreams show also index creation ...